# AspNetCore приложение в Docker. как работать с логами?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docker

Здравствуйте начал искать информацию как вытаскивать обычные текстовые логи из Docker контейнера и ничего не нашел.
Из этого я сделал вывод что если приложение работает в контейнере то логи пишутся  во внешние api по сетевому соединению (http).

Я пишу логи через Serilog.

```
var loggerConf = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(LevelSwitch)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Information)
    .WriteTo.File("logs/Main_Log.txt", LogEventLevel.Information, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .WriteTo.File("logs/Error_Log.txt", LogEventLevel.Error, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day);
  //.WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341", compact: true);
```

Как то баловался Seq сервером логирования, но с ним приложение, при активном (Debug) логировании, потребляло в 1,5 раза больше памяти,
инженеры тоже были настроены на чтение логов по старинке из текстовиков и я выключил Seq.
Много примеров про логирование Elasticsearch + Kibana, но с ними я не работал.

Вернусь к основному вопросу, можно ли работать с текстовыми логами в Docker контейнере?
Копировать их на хост машину, удалять старые файлы.
Или нужно обязательно смотреть в сторону сетевых технологий логирования?

Comment: Вам нужно почитать про Docker volume, это папки хоста, примонтированные к файловой системе контейнера

Comment: Спасибо почитаю!

Comment: Если у вас просто 1 проект, один сайт, то спокойно подключайте папочку к докеру и логгируйте туда. Если вы работаете с микросервисами, тогда есть разные подходы, но суть одна - в итоге логи должны быть где то в одном хранилище - будть то logstash+elastic+kibana или http запросы на сервис логгирования.

Comment: Спасибо!!  уже разобрался с монтированием папки.

Answer (score 0):

Как мне правильно подсказали я примантировал диск хоста.

1. d:/data - папка на хост системе
2. /app/logs - папка в контейнере

Такой необычный пусть к файлу (//d/data) для Win10.

Опции в docker-compose.yaml

```
volumes:
  - //d/data:/app/logs
```